# Black screen if no DVD drive is present

Tags: boot, kubuntu, kde, 14.04, optical

I have used an external USB-attached DVD drive to install Kubuntu 14.04 Beta 2, 64bit edition on an older HP Mini, without any problem (standard installation, auto-partition the hard drive, standard Plasma Desktop). Everything works **as long as the DVD drive is present during boot**. If I boot without the DVD drive (which is the normal mode for a portable device), I get the infamous black screen with mouse pointer. The KDE boot splash screen shows up, but before the last symbol (the KDE symbol) comes fully up, the screen slowly turns to black.

I can get a terminal with CTRL+ALT+F1, but if I do startx, I eventually get to the same black screen. Curiously, the guest account works (after a fashion), albeit with a somewhat mangled Plasma/Netbook-like desktop. This (and the fact that simply the presence of an optical drive fixes the problem) I take to mean it's not a driver problem, but probably is an issue with KDE?!?

I have spent a lot of time googling and trying various solutions (upgrading the system, doing a systems restore from grub, moving ~/.kde and let KDE rebuild, ...) but it seems that other people have not had this particular problem, or I am not asking the right question.

Any help is appreciated. I will gladly supply any further information for diagnostics.
/etc/fstab is identical with and without the DVD drive.

Comment: Haven't found a solution. I now also tried to re-flatten the machine, and re-install the newest Kubuntu version, this time from a USB stick, but the symptoms remained the same. Fade to black if no extenal DVD drive is connected. 

In the end, I gave up on Ubuntu and installed OpenSUSE (KDE version), which works like a charm, without any such problems.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem with different hardware (samsung n130, 32 bit, Kubuntu 14.04, KDELibs 4.13.3) and could solve the problem with the following steps:

1. *System settings > Workspace behaviour > Workspace*
2. *Global options for the Plasma Workspace*, changed *Workspace type* from *Desktop* to *Netbook*
3. Log-off, remove DVD-drive, Log-in (successful, including KDE)
4. *Workspace type* had changed to *Desktop*
5. after system restart the problem is still fixed